# Json Parse not working properly but works on jsontest

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, hosting

I am a new programmer, i am trying to build an app with Json.

I created Json parser class and in my main activity i have the following code :
 String url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";

```
                        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

one = json.getString(gridArray.get(lekeres).getTitle()); // one has the good value "two"

This works great. BUT

if i change url to : https://api.myjson.com/bins/3f8d2
 which is exactly the same code as in the jsontest, one doesn't have "two" . I searched for hours but i don't know why this is happening. I did nothing but change the url. The contest is the same...

Comment: what does `json.toString()` return ?

Comment: try your url with http instead of https, i guess problem is in fetching data, In my browser myjson.com certificate is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know how is your parser. I made a quick test and can read both link normally with this code:

> ```
>         try {
>             //url = new URL(""http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two2"); 
>             url = new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/3f8d2");
>             InputStream is = url.openStream();
>             JSONObject json = null;
>             BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
>             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>             int cp;
>             while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
>                 sb.append((char) cp);
>             }
>             String jsonText = sb.toString();
>             json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
>
>         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
> ```

This is more examples: http://en.proft.me/2013/12/5/how-parse-json-java/.
You can make your getJSONFromUrl similarly. Otherwise like other suggest try without `https://`.

Comment: WOW ! It's working thanks ! I think my parser was bad but i don't know why

Comment: @KnetigDavid: glad that works. Maybe you can look for more examples and fine tune your parser. Good luck.